# VPN Router does not reply to ARP Requests

Tags: vpn, routing, arp, ipv4

So i have these three network interfaces setup on a linux box:

> eth0 is facing the external network (192.168.1.0/24)
>  tun0 is the vpn interface (10.8.8.0/24)
>  eth1 is 
>    the local network interface (192.168.0.0/24)

The goal is to create a VPN Router, which routes only the packets from eth1 interface.

In order to do that I have a script that is run after the VPN connection has been established:

> **Allow rest of system to use default network connection** 
>  /sbin/ip route delete 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun0 
> /sbin/ip route delete
>   128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun0
>
> **Route all traffic from 192.168.0.0/24 through VPN** 
> /sbin/ip route add default via 10.8.8.1 dev tun0 table 200 
> /sbin/ip rule add from
>   192.168.0.0/24 table 200
>
> **VPN Forwarding (NAT)** 
> /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
>  /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -m state
>   --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>  /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

The problem is that, when the VPN tunnel is established, the linux box does not reply to ARP requests on eth1 interface. 
If i configure the ARP cache manually on a client PC, then the setup works fine.

Any ideas?

**EDIT :**  ARP works only when router makes a request to client PC but not the other way around (in that case router receives ARP but does not reply)

**EDIT 2 :** Both eth0 and eth1 share the same MAC-Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace  
`/sbin/ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/24 table 200`
 with
 `ip rule add iif eth1 table 200` 
We dont want only packets from 192.168.0.0/24 to use routing table 200 but every packet from interface eth1.